MongoDB BSONSerializer adding extra decimals
We have a C# application that creates a MongoDB Aggregation query using the C# Driver. which also has some double values.
 var distanceScript = Properties.Resources.SEARCH_STEP2_ADD_DISTANCE;
 distanceScript = distanceScript.Replace("<LONGITUDE>", criteria.Location[0].ToString());
 distanceScript = distanceScript.Replace("<LATITUDE>", criteria.Location[1].ToString());
 var distanceDocument = new BsonDocument { { "$addFields", Utils.GetProjectQuery(distanceScript) } };


  public static BsonDocument GetProjectQuery(string queryPath)
  {
      return BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(queryPath);
  }

But when the GetProjectQuery (which deserialize the string in to a BsonDocument) is executed it always adds extra decimals to the end of the double values.
eg: expected output should be:
{
                "geoWithin" : {
                    "circle" : {
                        "center" : {
                            "type" : "Point",
                            "coordinates" : [
                                58.3575487,
                                23.5880847
                            ]
                        },
                        "radius" : 15000
                    },
                    "path" : "Store.Location"
                }
            }

Actual output:
{
                "geoWithin" : {
                    "circle" : {
                        "center" : {
                            "type" : "Point",
                            "coordinates" : [
                                58.357548700000002,
                                23.5880847
                            ]
                        },
                        "radius" : 15000
                    },
                    "path" : "Store.Location"
                }
            }

Any idea why is that and how i could eliminate that.

Can you edit your question to include the code in GetProjectQuery and an example showing the values you expect and the values you get

@stuartd updated.

58.357548700000002 has 17 significant digits.  A rough estimate of the double precision representation gives an exponent  of 5(1028), and a mantissa with 54 bits, which exceeds double.  This implies some other datatype is being used in the conversion process.

From debugging on the local side, I noticed that the values are deserialized as BsonDouble which I believe is the default behavior when the BsonSerializer deals with the decimal/double value.
As you are deserializing from the JSON string, neither custom serializers nor custom serializer providers are working to deal with decimal/double (de)serialization unless you are (de)serializing the value from the mentioned type.
Hence, the quickest and easiest way (although this may looks dirty) is you should post-process the value by overwriting with Decimal128 type after deserialize to BsonDocument.
var distanceDocument = new BsonDocument { { "$addFields", Utils.GetProjectQuery(distanceScript) } };

distanceDocument["geoWithin"]["circle"]["center"]["coordinates"][0] 
    = new Decimal128(result["geoWithin"]["circle"]["center"]["coordinates"][0].ToDecimal());
distanceDocument["geoWithin"]["circle"]["center"]["coordinates"][1] 
    = new Decimal128(result["geoWithin"]["circle"]["center"]["coordinates"][1].ToDecimal());

Alternatively,
distanceDocument["geoWithin"]["circle"]["center"]["coordinates"] = BsonArray.Create(
    (distanceDocument["geoWithin"]["circle"]["center"]["coordinates"] as BsonArray)
        .Select(x => new Decimal128(x.ToDecimal()))
);

